# Qwizard in qt does not show Finish and cancel button on window 8 same code works on 7

Tags: c++, qt, windows-8, windows-7

As you can see below [image]

`Qwizard` does not show Finish and cancel button on window 8 but does on windows 7 with the same code. How can I obtain the same behavior on both platforms ?

Answer (score 1):

Cannot say anything without the code, but it seems you haven't explicitly specified which buttons to put on your wizard. There may be different [wizard options](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#WizardOption-enum) set from one OS to another (eg `QWizard::NoDefaultButton` might be set on windows 8 )

So either this should do the trick :

Always unset the `QWizard::NoDefaultButton` wizard option :

```
this->setOption(QWizard::NoDefaultButton, false);
```

Or manually manage the buttons :

```
QList<WizardButton> buttonLayout;
buttonLayout << QWizard::FinishButton << QWizard::CancelButton;
this->setButtonLayout(layout);
```

Comment: Hi UmNyobe, Thankyou for reply. I have found that if i set "this->setFixedSize(600, 500);" of QWizard then Finish and Cancel button disappear from bottom in win8 but works on win7. if i did not setFixedSize both buttons are visible in win8 also.